# Upgrading from 4.0.2 to 4.2.0 breaks paper_trail code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, paper-trail-gem

I am getting the following error in 4.2.0 which works in 4.0.2:

undefined method `reverse!' for #

in the following line of code:

```
 def show
    @client     = Client.find(params[:id])
    @versions   = @client.versions.reverse!   <-- error line
  end
```

typing in @client.versions.class yields the following:

```
>> @client.versions.class
=> PaperTrail::Version::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
>>
```

Any idea anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't even be trying to use the destructive `reverse!` method, that (if it worked) alters the array it's being called on. Thankfully that's been removed from the underlying classes. Instead you should just use `reverse` which still returns a reversed array, but doesn't alter the array it's being called on.

Comment: Many thanks, plain 'reverse' worked.  A follow up question though, how does one go about finding out that this method was removed from underlying classes?

Comment: There's no easy way - you have to dig through changelogs or the commits themselves. The fact that it's hard to know that is one of the reasons why it's best to use the right method to begin with :)